Correlating two space time layers
I have two point datasets, both showing the x,y location and date of separate events (1. environmental event,2. detection of bacteria). I'm trying to understand their spatial and temporal relationship. I'm not quite sure which tool to use in ArcGIS Pro 2.7.1 to do this. I tried to use Find Time Space Matches and expanded the temporal and spatial area, but I can't figure out how to make sure that the tool shouldn't look back in time (e.g. if an environmental event occurred on Jan 10 then I would only want to look for bacteria events after that, but if I pick a 5 day temporal radius, then a Jan 10 event would match with any bacteria event between Jan 5th and Jan 15th).
I've done a bit of research online and it seems like a space time cube might be the way to go, but those seem to be limited to a single variable. Should I be making a space time cube for both event types and then seeing how well they correlate? Is that even possible?
